# Adding gift message to the packing slip and one-page checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, packing-slip

There doesn't seem to be an option to add the gift message to the packing slip and the one-page checkout.
I've found a few guides online but they're all rather old; I was hoping someone might have some more up-to-date advice.

I'm running Magento 1.9 and have currently tried the example outlined [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/add-gift-message-to-magentos-pdf-packingslip/) but with no real success.

Answer (score 0):

Magento by default provide gift message module.

For that, goto **System >> Configuration >> Sales >> Sales**

Expand **Gift Options** tab. If you want to add whole order message then only set yes to **Allow Gift Messages on Order Level** or you can set order item wise message.

Comment: I've done that and it still doesn't appear on either the emails or the one-page checkout.